# Is there a SMTP mail transfer library in PHP

Tags: php, smtp

I want to write an email transfer service and need a MTU replacement of sendmail/postfix.

I'm not looking how to deliver to a transmitting SMTP server (like a postfix listing on a SMTP port). I also don't need the receiving part of the server, bounces etc. would go to a different existing postfix.

All of it in pure PHP. SMTP is a pretty easy protocol but this would require access to the MX DNS record and other lot of details that need to be taken care of.

Why do i need this? Because most shared internet providers have insane low limits for sending out emails like 500 per day. Thats almost nothing if you want to setup even the lowest traffic email list.

EDIT: Please Note: **The code needs to connect to the receivers SMTP server and deliver the message with an adapted header set (removed BCC list, added Path route).** If you see a SMTP class less then 5000 lines or requires you to configure a SMTP hostip and port then this is not the stuff i'm looking for.

It needs to do all the stuff sendmail is doing just as a PHP library.

Comment: I doubt PHP alone would do the job, you need MX records and what not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [Pear's Mail](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail) class.

**EDIT**

After re-reading this, I see there's more to it than just a library.  You are asking to send direct to the remote MX.

Why reinvent the wheel?  Set up an instance of postfix on the server, which only listens to connections from the web server... and let an MTA do what it does best.  Hand off the messages from php to a real mail server and move on.

In the case of ISP's that block outbound port 25 and force the use of a smarthost, this also allows you to restrict the rate of messages sent to the smarthost.

Lastly, sending straight to the end MX from your php script is a bad idea, because if you send to me, I'll never get it.  I and many other sites use "greylisting" to reduce spam, which denies all initial requests with a 450 temporary error.  Real MTA's will try again, but unless you implemented a delay queue and try again, your message will never go through.

Comment: No also just a SMTP Client but no SMTP Mail Transfer Agent

Comment: A delay queue is of course on the feature list. Before i read your answer it was just for reliability and performance (multiple MX lookups). 

The answer of why is that many people only have a php account or they are not able to install postfix (or don't want it for the high memory footprint on a cheap VPS) like me - by the way you can't install postfix as a non root. This unix email MTU's suck so much.

And a 500 emails per day on an otherwise good webspace provider is a showstopper for a mailing list. I asked why he don't want to increase the limit but he don't want.

Comment: Well, you can still use Pear's Net_SMTP to make the connections, and probably a Pear module to look up the MX record.  Then you can check the return code from the delivery attempt and cache the message yourself if you get a 4xx error.

Answer (score 1):

We use http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/ to do SMTP email from PHP

Comment: No also just a SMTP Client but no SMTP Mail Transfer Agent.

Answer (score 1):

[SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) is the only library you'll need.

Comment: No also just a SMTP Client but no SMTP Mail Transfer Agent

Comment: Oh, sorry I haven't read the whole question. I don't know any MTA implementation in PHP, sorry. =\

Comment: I think you are right. After 2 days of intensive searching i found only a commerical product that you can install on your site to setup a complete email service including SMTP server like php cron jobs. 

But the most important parts like MX record query is available in basic PHP i think it's time to write a system on my own.

Answer (score 0):

Try Zend Framework component Zend_Mail (you can use the component independently of the entire framework).

Comment: This is not an MTU implementation. It delivers the email to your SMTP server but not the receivers SMTP server.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something I wrote. It's quite minimal and I don't know how well it performs, but I wrote it with the intention of replacing sendmail, meaning that it will take a message, lookup all the MX records for the recipient domains, contact those mail servers and deliver a message for the corresponding recipients. It worked well enough for me at the time.

https://github.com/denvertimothy/ThriveSMTP

It's been a long time since I've used it, but I threw it up on Github just now.

Answer (score 0):

I used http://www.mailerq.com/ which works cool. Its a queue based mail transfer agent. It requires rabbitmq.
It provides multiple worker as well.easy to store in database.
It provided management console as well.
worth to check it