# Contact form in php doesnt receive mail for hotmail

Tags: php

I m trying contact form in php.I receive the mails in gmail,yahoo etc but doesnt recieve any mails in hotmail.I tried a lot but doesnt know whats the problem.Why i cant recieve mail in hotmail? Here is the code.

```
if (empty($error)) {

     $to = 'abc@gmail.com, ' . $email;
    $subject = " contact form message";
     $repEmail = 'abc@gmail.com';
       $headers = 'From:  Contact Detail <'.$repEmail.'>'.$eol;
    $content =  "Contact Details: \n 
Name:$name \n 
Batch:  $batch \n
 Email:  $email \n   
mobile:  $mobile " ;
 $success = "<b>Thank you! Your message has been sent!</b>";
    mail($to,$subject,$content,$headers);

    }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Did you check the trash?

Comment: ya checked..But there is no mail there too

Comment: you better refer this question    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13324649/mail-not-being-received-by-hotmail-com

Answer (score 0):

Check the server admin's email for bounce messages. I would guess it has to do with hotmail rejecting it either because it doesn't like your host or because you don't have SPF or DKIM signing set up. Either way, the blame is probably on your server email administrator more than on your code. Email is actually kinda complex to set up nowadays given all the anti-spam stuff you have to do.

You might want to consider using a third party email service. SMTP through a gmail account or Amazon SES so they'll take care of more of these details. This can be set up by the server admin too, or done in PHP with libraries. [Is there a SMTP mail transfer library in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306480/is-there-a-smtp-mail-transfer-library-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

this is more likely

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['email']))
//if "email" is filled out, send email
  {
  //send email
  $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
  $subject = 'Order' ;
  $message = 
   'Product Name :'. $_REQUEST['proname']."\n". //these all are example details
   'Name :'.$_REQUEST['name']."\n".
   'Phone :'. $_REQUEST['phone']."\n".
   'City :'.$_REQUEST['city']."\n".
   'Address :'.$_REQUEST['address']."\n".
   'Quantity :'. $_REQUEST['select']; 

if ($email == "" || $subject == "" || $message == ""  )
    {
    echo 'Please fill the empty fields';
    }
else{ 
  mail("anything@something.com", $subject,
  $message, "From:" . $email);
  echo 'Thank you ! we will contact you soon';
}

  }
```